# I need advice on if my abstract class should be an interface (or vice versa)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have an inheritance hierarchy modelling entities within my JavaFX game. I have 4 enemy types within my game however, they only need the default implementation of methods in Entity (abstract class) + 1 extra method in which each enemy will provide a different implementation for. There will be no more enemies in the future as well. So from this background, I believe Enemy should be an interface.

So my question is, am I correct in assuming Enemy should be an Interface over an abstract class?

Here is my class diagram (currently with enemy as an abstract class):

[image: Class Diagram]

Comment: If Enemy is a interface, it can't extend Entity anymore, since it's an abstract class.

Comment: @Héctor Enemy wouldn't extend entity, instead the individual Enemy types would

Comment: You could have Enemies that aren't Entities in that case.

Comment: In that case, wherever you need a Enemy, you won't be able to use Entity methods, but only Enemy ones.

Comment: @matt I know, but I feel like it's a waste to have an abstract class with 1 abstract method in it?

Comment: @Héctor No. Each Enemy type will extend from Entity, but implement the Enemy interface

Comment: @Daniel but imagine one method that receives an `Enemy`, inside that method you won't be able to do `enemy.getCurrentCell()`, for instance. That's because,`getcurrentCell()` is not a Enemy method but an Entity method.

Comment: If you're deriving from an abstract class, you should probably extend the abstract class, because it still manages data. The heiarchy is pretty solidly Entity -> Enemy, so either make an Entity interface, and an abstract version, or make Enemy an abstract class.

Comment: @Héctor You raise a good point, you are right I have situations where I only need to know if its an Enemy. Therefore if i used an interface for enemy, I would not be able to access methods from Entity

Comment: @Daniel I have another solution to allow Enemy to be an interface. Create an interface `IEntity` and put Entity public methods there. `Entity` will implement `IEntity`. Then `Enemy` will extend `IEntity`. And finally, each concrete enemy implement `Enemy` and extends `Entity`. This way,  you can call `IEntity` methods from an Enemy: `enemy.getCurrentCell()`

Answer (score 1):

The choice of interface over abstract class is always good as it enables `extension` of your application.

Before to Java-8 abstract classes were a way to provide shared partial implementations as before to java-8 interfaces can't have method definitions.

> In Java-8, interfaces have default methods which allow definition shared implementations.

Hence, my recommendation is use interface here &  provide default methods. And if you need to provide some additional implementation beyond contract you can always  opt in for abstract impl or concrete impls.

In your case, any representation of an entity should be backed by interface.

So, your diagram look something like below

```
interface Entity extends cloneable{
//...
}

interface Enemy extends Entity{
//...
}

interface User extends Entity, Serializable{
//...
}

class Player implements  User {
//...
}

class Dragon implements Enemy{
//...
}
```

Comment: After thinking about it more, there are cases in which I'm only aware if an object is an Enemy. If Enemy was an interface in this case, I would not be able to access the much needed methods inherited from Entity.

Comment: Well! Entity should also be an interface. That's where I am saying setup the contract part and any customisation should be done in more concrete implementation by implementing interfaces. E.g. Enemy, User both are entity type but not all users have same behavior and no all enemies have same behavior but they have certain attributes in common (should be in interface). And any behavioral difference should be in concrete implementation.

Comment: I understand what your saying. However, in my case the Entity abstract class does indeed provide default implementations for methods required by User & all Enemy whom won't have any need to override the default implementations

Comment: So, you can provide default impl  in interfaces java-8 onwards. did you actually read my answer?

Comment: Yes I read your answer, however what would be the benefit of converting Entity from an abstract class to an Interface when as an abstract class it already provides default implementation

Comment: `extension` is the advantage. One example is - if Enemy extends Entity it would not be able to extend any other class.

Comment: I understand this. However in my case , Enemy will only ever need to extend Entity. I have a set specification, and once completed nothing new will change/added.

Comment: Daniel if you think your requirement will never change you can do anything :)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, some of your points you raised about interfaces I wasn't aware of and will be definitely using them in other parts of my project. But, for the entity hierarchy I think abstract classes will be better suited after taken in considerations from everyone input here.

Answer (score 0):

Through-out my coding experience, whenever I relied on an abstract class for the purpose of abstraction, I was always proven wrong with time. Typically, in OOP, one class can be different things to different consumers, so, in order to have that flexibility and avoid hitting a future limitation due to the fact that a class can have one parent only, I learned that abstractions should always be interfaces.

Abstract classes on the other hand are used to offer common functionality to different interface implementations, but even in that case, I would try to "favor composition over inheritance".

So, my advice is to always program to interfaces.